# Creating iOS app using Swift and need to know how to keep track of users data using mysql database?

Tags: ios, mysql, iphone, xcode, swift

I am creating an iOS app using Swift and XCode, I want users to be able to log in and out and allow them to post through my app. I know that I need a database for this, I don't know how to link a mySql database with my code. Can someone help?

Comment: It would help us to help you if you posted some code or and explanation of what you have tried so far (and where you are stuck).  You may want to take a look at "How do I ask a good question" ) in the Help Center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Your question as currently posed is a little vague to give a quality answer to.  The more specifics we have to work with, the more likely it is that answers will be relevant or helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Like @frashnian stated, you need to do something on your own and when you encounter an error you are unable to solve, you post it here for possible solution.

I think you can start learning about iOS/SQLite from here: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_8_Application_using_Swift_and_FMDB